# can TextWebSocketFrame be declared with static and final?

Tags: websocket, static, netty, bytebuffer, java-websocket

In Netty, send messages are like this:

```java
channel.writeAndFlush(new TextWebSocketFrame("Operation Succeed"));
```

to run this code, nothing abnormal. so I think, argument from writeAndFlush can be extracted to a static and final variable like this:

```java
public class LogicHandler extends SimpleUserEventChannelHandler<WebSocketServerProtocolHandler.HandshakeComplete> {
    static final TextWebSocketFrame SUCCEED = new TextWebSocketFrame("Operation Succeed");

    @Override
    protected void eventReceived(ChannelHandlerContext context, WebSocketServerProtocolHandler.HandshakeComplete arg) {
        context.channel().writeAndFlush(SUCCEED.retain()); // the client received empty content
    } 
}
```

to run this codes,
abnormal things happen:

###### the client(WebSocket from Chrome browser) received the message but empty content

Are there any ideas that i can do with it?

remove the method "retain" can not solve the problem, the only way is to remove static and final keyword.

Comment: Then why not remove static/final if that works? Not sure why you use retain, this comment gives some explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52884904/18703

Comment: take more usage and be more effective.  i also tried ReferenceCountUtil.retain(message) but no use. retain method just change the internal value of its self, the declaration seems no problem.  there's a lot of scenes can be done like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the underlying ByteBuf's readerIndex is updated once used. You can reuse it by reset the readerIndex, like below. But this code is thread-unsafe, it can cause problems when there are multiple connections.

```
public static class LogicHandler extends SimpleUserEventChannelHandler<WebSocketServerProtocolHandler.HandshakeComplete> {
    static final TextWebSocketFrame SUCCEED = new TextWebSocketFrame("Operation Succeed");

    @Override
    protected void eventReceived(ChannelHandlerContext context, WebSocketServerProtocolHandler.HandshakeComplete arg) {
        SUCCEED.content().readerIndex(0);
        context.channel().writeAndFlush(SUCCEED.retain());
    }
}
```

This is thread-safe

```
public static class LogicHandler extends SimpleUserEventChannelHandler<WebSocketServerProtocolHandler.HandshakeComplete> {
    static final TextWebSocketFrame SUCCEED = new TextWebSocketFrame("Operation Succeed");

    @Override
    protected void eventReceived(ChannelHandlerContext context, WebSocketServerProtocolHandler.HandshakeComplete arg) {
        context.channel().writeAndFlush(SUCCEED.retainedDuplicate());
    }
}
```

Comment: thx. retainedDuplicate does not work either.  still it returns empty string, but readerIndex(0) real worked but thread-unsafe. i am trying to solve this